# OpenApi error upon reference to other file NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I want to have reference to other yaml file in my NodeJS project.

My main yaml file look like this

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: test
  description: Description
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:3000
    variables:
      basePath:
        default: /
    description: Local server with default port
paths:
  /sign-in:
    post:
      summary: Test.
      description: Test.
      requestBody:
        $ref: "test.yaml"
      responses:
        '200':
          $ref: "test.yaml"
```

test.yaml file look like this:

```
description: Optional description in
required: true
content:
  application/json:
    schema:
      type: object
      required:
         - id
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
```

And I'm getting error on my generated swagger documentation

[image]

For generating swagger i use https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express

My swagger-ui config:

```
app.use(OpenApiValidator.middleware({
    apiSpec: 'schemas/openapi.yaml',
    validateRequests: true,
    validateResponses: true
}));
```

Using ./test.yaml instead of test.yaml didn't work